# CakePHP 2.0 not loading custom helpers when exceptions occur

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm creating a CakePHP application but whenever an Exception is thrown (e.g. Security exceptions amongst others) any custom helpers are not loaded. This causes the page to error and the helper not loaded error is displayed instead of the exception.

My helpers are all loaded in AppController and I have no problem with them most of the time. I've just added the Security component to protect against CSRF but whenever I simulate CSRF, I get the following error:

```
    Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$HelperName [CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 804]

    View::__get() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 804
    include - APP/View/Layouts/default.ctp, line 105
    View::_evaluate() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 908
    View::_render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 872
    View::renderLayout() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 527
    View::render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 471
    Controller::render() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 959
    ExceptionRenderer::_outputMessage() - CORE/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 263
    ExceptionRenderer::error400() - CORE/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 209
    ExceptionRenderer::render() - CORE/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 165
    ErrorHandler::handleException() - CORE/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php, line 127
    [main] - [internal], line ??
```

It is only ever my custom helpers though, never the core ones. I want to display the exception error and for the custom helper to be included as helps with a core part of the layout.

Any help you can give will be fantastic.

Comment: This was a bug, but was fixed: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2274

Comment: Ah thanks! Updating solved that problem

Comment: @chrisbulmer Which version did you use to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you answer your own question to know what the solution was (I know you said that in comments, but people can miss that) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this was a bug which has now been fixed -  [cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2274](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2274) (Thanks to tigrang).